# Reading Data from CFReadStream and Converting it into NSString

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, json, cfreadstream

I am having a problem with my iPhone application that I am building. The app sends a JSON request to a python server and then reads the JSON response from the server. I have the following function that sends data to the server and gets the response and puts it into NSData. (I took out the server address for the post)

```
+(NSData *)accessServer:(NSMutableDictionary *) dic needResponse:(BOOL) response
{
    // Conect to the server
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStringRef remoteHost = CFSTR("");
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, remoteHost, 5687, &readStream, &writeStream);
    CFWriteStreamOpen(writeStream);
    CFReadStreamOpen(readStream);

    // send data
    NSData *json = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dic options:0 error:nil];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:json encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    jsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", jsonString, @"\r\n\r\n"];
    UInt8 *writeBuf = (UInt8 *)[jsonString UTF8String];
    int writtenBytes = 0;
    int bytesToSend = (int)[jsonString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    while(writtenBytes < bytesToSend)
    {
        writtenBytes += CFWriteStreamWrite(writeStream, writeBuf, bytesToSend-writtenBytes);
    }
    NSLog(@"Done sending, Sent :%d Total: %d",writtenBytes,bytesToSend);
    CFWriteStreamClose(writeStream);
    if(response)
    {
        // get the return data
        uint8_t readData[10000];
        int readBytes = 1;
        int totalRead = 0;
        while(readBytes > 0)
        {
            readBytes = (int)CFReadStreamRead(readStream, readData, 10000);
            totalRead += readBytes;
        }
        CFReadStreamClose(readStream);
        return [[NSData alloc]initWithBytes:readData length:totalRead];
    }
    else
    {
        CFReadStreamClose(readStream);
        return nil;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I attempted to take the NSData and convert it into a NSString it has a length of 0 and the NSData has a length > 0. The following code is how I take the NSData and convert it to NSString.

```
NSData *t = [Globals accessServer:getLocationData needResponse:TRUE];
NSString *tempString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:t encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

This problem seems to happen about 10% of the time. Sometimes it won't happen for an hour and sometimes it happens like 10 times in a row. Any help is appreciated and please let me know if you need any more information that I may have forgotten to put in this.